# How to get HttpServletRequest in Liferay WebService

Tags: web-services, liferay

Hi I have a webService that is generated from buildServices of Liferay.. 
the method looks like this

```
 public User getUserTest(long userId) {

    User u = null;
    try {
        Token token = OAuthFactoryUtil.createToken("sasa", "sdad");
    } catch (OAuthException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        u = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUser(userId);
        System.out.println("xx user " + u.getScreenName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(" Exception ************* " + e.toString());
    }

    return u;
}
```

the parameters in this ws would be this :

```
http://localhost:8080/demo-portlet/api/json?serviceClassName=com.sample.portlet.library.service.BookServiceUtil&serviceMethodName=getUserTest&userId=10195&serviceParameters=[userId]
```

having `userId` as a parameter..

How would you pass a parameter if you need `HttpServletRequest`.. my method would look like this

```
public User getUserTest(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {

    User u = null;

    try {

        String version = httpRequest.getHeader("X-PHM-APP-VERSION");
        Token token = OAuthFactoryUtil.createToken("sasa", "sdad");
    } catch (OAuthException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        String authorization = httpRequest.getHeader("Authorization");
        u = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUser(Long.valueOf(authorization));
        System.out.println("authorization --> " + authorization);
        System.out.println("xx user " + u.getScreenName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(" Exception ************* " + e.toString());
    }

    return u;
}
```

I need the `HttpServletRequest` to get the parameters from header, instead of passing through url. Is there a better way to get parameters from header? thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

I think webservice layer is normally at a later stage where in you would never pass request. Ideally what you would do is pass header parameter to the webservice instead of request

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sandeep, actually thats exactly what I need, passing header parameter, how would I do that. That is the reason why I need this HttpServletRequest, to get the header parameter. Thanks

Comment: Clint normally we invoke web service from a controller, which would have request available. I think you will be writing first a client which would be invoked from controller or something. Can't you get request there and pass it from there on?

Answer (score 0):

In Liferay, you will get `HttpServletRequest` from the `PortletRequest`. Please use `com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil` class.

There are 2 methods in it. `getHttpServletRequest()` and `getOriginalServletRequest()`, you will get the both core level http request from these methods.

Comment: for getting the httpServletRequest you would need portletRequest, now how would you pass a portletRequest to a web-service method, so we are back from where we started :-). Also is it not that the web-service should be programming language agnostic and providing the parameter as  httpServletRequest i.e. asking the consumer to send a httpServletRequest would tie it to Java and destroy the very purpose? I would like to know if this is at all possible, as I am also learning WS and am fairly new to it. Thanks

Comment: I just shown a way to extract the parameter, one can call web service by passing String parameter, just a way to extract parameter!

Comment: @FelixChristy How do I get the PortletRequest using this API?